# Convert series datetime data into total hours

Tags: python, html, django, pandas, numpy

I've a dataframe named mainData_Frame with column 'Clearance Time' in the following format.

Clearance Time
2 days 22:43:00
1 days 12:32:23
5 days 23:44:13
.
.
.
.

I need to convert all timedelta series at 'Clearance Time' column into numeric hours. What I applied is the following codes:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

def convert_to_hours(time_string):
    time = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_string, '%d days %H:%M:%S')
    delta = datetime.timedelta(days=time.day, hours=time.hour, minutes=time.minute, seconds=time.second)
    return delta.total_seconds()/3600

timeData = pd.Series(mainData_Frame['Clearance Time'])
num_Hours = timeData.apply(convert_to_hours)

print(num_Hours)
```

### But got the following errors:

TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Timedelta

I'm the beginner in python and having some project regarding this, please help to sort out.

Comment: Since it expects a `str`, you could try to use `str(time_string)` (which is not a good variable name as it is of type Timedelta) to costruct a string from the Timedelta.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a function here, use [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) *built-ins* :

```
ser = pd.to_timedelta(mainData_Frame["Clearance Time"])
​
timeData = ser.dt.total_seconds().div(3600)
​
```

Output :

```
print(timeData)

0     70.716667
1     36.539722
2    143.736944
Name: Clearance Time, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, simply it is done. relieved so much for now.....Keep Supporting.